# Internationalizing a Python 2.6 application via Babel

Tags: python, internationalization, translation, gettext, python-babel

We're evaluating Babel 0.9.5 [1] under Windows for use with Python 2.6 and have the following questions that we we've been unable to answer through reading the documentation or googling.

1) I would like to use an _ like abbreviation for ungettext. Is there a concencus on whether one should use n_ or N_ for this?

n_ does not appear to work. Babel does not extract text.

N_ appears to partially work. Babel extracts text like it does for gettext, but does not format for ngettext (missing plural argument and msgstr[ n ].)

2) Is there a way to set the initial msgstr fields like the following when creating a POT file?

I suspect there may be a way to do this via Babel cfg files, but I've been unable to find documentation on the Babel cfg file format.

"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"Language-Team: en_US \n"

3) Is there a way to preserve 'obsolete' msgid/msgstr's in our PO files? When I use the Babel update command, newly created obsolete strings are marked with #~ prefixes, but existing obsolete message strings get deleted.

Thanks,
Malcolm

[1] http://babel.edgewall.org/

Comment: Why you don't want to use just GNU gettext utilities ported to win32 for extracting the messages? http://gnuwin32.sf.net

Comment: Hi Bializ: Installing the GNU gettext utlities is not convenient for our customers who maintain their own PO files. Another advantage of the Babel utilities is that they work in UTF-8 mode by default. We've had some problems getting the GNU gettext utilities to do this consistently (they default to ASCIII).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `pybabel extract` recognizes the following keywords: `_`, `gettext`, `ngettext`, `ugettext`, `ungettext`, `dgettext`, `dngettext`,`N_`. Use [`-k` option](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/cmdline.html#extract) to add others. `N_` is often used for [NULL-translations](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#deferred-translations) (also called deferred translations).

**Update**: The `-k` option can list arguments of function to be put in catalog. So, if you use `n_ = ngettext` try `pybabel extract -k n_:1,2 ...`.

Comment: Hi Denis: Thank you for your help. I'm aware of the -k option, but can't find a way to map N_ or n_ to the ngettext function so that these function's parameters get processed as plurals (creating msgid_plural, msgid[0], etc) vs. an alias of gettext. I appreciate the reference to the use of N_ as a NULL translation. This seems like a Python specific syntax (?) as opposed to other language gettext implementations which support N_ or n_ as ngettext aliases.

Comment: Hi Denis: Your "-k n_:1,2" technique works perfectly - thank you very much!! For the archives: We've decided to use N_ vs. n_ to follow what look likes the defacto industry standard for ngettext abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

To answer question 2):

If you run Babel via `pybabel extract`, you can set `Project-Id-Version` via the `--project` and `--version` options.

If you run Babel via `setup.py extract_messages`, then `Project-Id-Version` is taken from the distribution (project name and version in the setup.py file).

Both ways also support the options `--msgid-bugs-address` and `--copyright-holder` for setting the POT metadata.